# pass string in SSRS parameter, without double quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am trying to allow the user to pass a  text parameter in an SSRS report like this:

```
'value1','value2','value3','value4'
```

The idea is to use it in my dataset query in a where in clause.

I think SSRS passes the above parameter to the query like this:

`"'value1','value2','value3','value4'"` which messes up my query.

How can this work?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can definitely do that,
You need to create parameter as below
[image]

Then If you are using sql statement you can use in your sql statement as

```
select * from customer where customerid=@ReportParameter1
```

Here are 2 links for Ref

https://reportsyouneed.com/ssrs-tip-put-parameters-in-your-query-not-your-filter/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tutorial-add-a-parameter-to-your-report-report-builder?view=sql-server-2017#Query